# Apply service packs (.msu file) update using powershell scripts on local server

Tags: .net, powershell, deployment, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

What it basically does is the script gets the .msu files from a location and copies to the "C:\temp\" folder.
Then the script gets all the .msu files and stores the names in the array.
Using the foreach loop it tries to apply the .msu updates to the local server where the script is running.

However when i run the script. It doesn't do anything.

Below is the code

```
$from="sourceLocation\*.msu"
$to="C:\temp\"
Copy-Item $from $to -Recurse -Force
$listOfMSUs= (Get-ChildItem –Path $to -Filter "*.msu").Name
Write-Host $listOfMSUs

if($listOfMSUs)
{
    foreach($msu in $listOfMSUs)
    {
    Write-Host "Processing The Update"
    &  wusa $to$msu /quiet /norestart         
    }
}
else{

Write-Host "MSUs doesnt exists"
}
```

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was simple. All i needed was a /install command parameter.
So the line should be

```
 & wusa /install $to$msu  /quiet /norestart 

 OR

  & wusa $to$msu  /quiet /norestart
```

Answer (score 2):

You're copying the file(s) to a *local* folder (`C:\temp`), but run `wusa` on a *remote* host. That host may have the same local folder, but you didn't copy the update(s) to that folder. If you want to install the updates from a local folder on a remote host, you must copy them to that folder on the remote host:

```
Copy-Item $from "\\$hostname\$($to -replace ':','$')" -Recurse -Force
```

---

**Edit:** Since you want to install the updates on the host running the script your code should work in general, although I'd streamline it a little, e.g. like this:

```
$from = "sourceLocation\*.msu"
$to   = 'C:\temp'

Copy-Item $from $to -Recurse -Force

$updates = @(Get-ChildItem –Path $to -Filter '*.msu')
if ($updates.Count -ge 1) {
  $updates | % {
    Write-Host "Processing update $($_.Name)."
    & wusa $_.FullName /quiet /norestart
  }
} else {
  Write-Host 'No updates found.'
}
```

Is UAC enabled on the host? In that case you need to run the Script "as Administrator" when running it manually, or with the option "run with highest privileges" checked when running the script as a scheduled task.

Comment: Hi Ansgar. I am not sure if i got the question right to be honest. The server in this case is my local server and the files are copied on that local folder.

Comment: @Sike12 Do you want to install the updates on the host where the script is running? Or do you want to install them on a remote host?

Comment: Yes Ansgar i want to run them on the host where the script is running. I tried with this command but it doesnt do anything.                wusa "C:\Temp\Windows6.1-KB2506143-x64.msu" /quiet /norestart  . HOwever i have updated the question

Comment: @Sike12 See updated answer. Is UAC enabled on your server and, in case it is, did you run the script with elevated privileges? What exactly do you mean by "doesn't do anything"? Does it fail to copy the files? Does it fail to install them? Do you get error messages or any other kind of response?

Comment: Hi Ansgar This is the error i get in the event viewer.                          Windows update  could not be installed because of error 2147942487 "The parameter is incorrect." (Command line: ""C:\WINDOWS\system32\wusa.exe"  /install C:\temp\Windows6.1-KB2506143-x64.msu /norestart")

Comment: @Sike12 `wusa.exe` does not have a parameter `/install`. Check `wusa /?`.

Comment: whether or not you supply the parameter it does the installation. I have tested both command and it works.