# Installing the Active Directory PowerShell Module on Windows 10

Tags: powershell, active-directory, windows-10

I'm trying to install the active directory module of powershell on windows 10, through this group of commands provided by technet, but I still cannot succeed, I've tried many times and also running the powershell as administrator but the problem remains, it looks like it gets stuck inside a loop printing: "." 
I downloaded the code from this [link](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Install-the-Active-fd32e541) (It comes in a .txt file)

Also I'm attaching the code itself and a screenshot of my result after executing the code.

Basically the code provided creates a function called Install-ADModule and then invokes it:

```
#requires -RunAsAdministrator

<#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Ashley McGlone, Microsoft Premier Field Engineer
http://aka.ms/goateepfe
February 2016
Install-ADModule
For Windows 10 performs the following tasks:
- Downloads and installs Windows 10 RSAT for the appropriate system architecture
- Enables the RSAT AD PowerShell feature
- Updates help for the AD module
- Displays validation output
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
LEGAL DISCLAIMER
This Sample Code is provided for the purpose of illustration only and is not
intended to be used in a production environment.  THIS SAMPLE CODE AND ANY
RELATED INFORMATION ARE PROVIDED "AS IS" WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EITHER
EXPRESSED OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF
MERCHANTABILITY AND/OR FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  We grant You a
nonexclusive, royalty-free right to use and modify the Sample Code and to
reproduce and distribute the object code form of the Sample Code, provided
that You agree: (i) to not use Our name, logo, or trademarks to market Your
software product in which the Sample Code is embedded; (ii) to include a valid
copyright notice on Your software product in which the Sample Code is embedded;
and (iii) to indemnify, hold harmless, and defend Us and Our suppliers from and
against any claims or lawsuits, including attorneys’ fees, that arise or result
from the use or distribution of the Sample Code.

This posting is provided "AS IS" with no warranties, and confers no rights. Use
of included script samples are subject to the terms specified
at http://www.microsoft.com/info/cpyright.htm.
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------#>


<#
.SYNOPSIS
Installs the AD PowerShell module from RSAT for Windows 10
.DESCRIPTION
Performs the following tasks:
- Downloads and installs Windows 10 RSAT for the appropriate system architecture
- Enables the RSAT AD PowerShell feature
- Updates help for the AD module
- Displays validation output
.NOTES
Requires an elevated PowerShell host.

Requires an internet connection to download the RSAT install.

The RSAT hotfix download (<100MB) will be stored in the Downloads
folder of the user running the script.

Checks the following before taking action:
- Is the system running Windows 10?
- Is the RSAT already installed?
- Is the AD PowerShell feature already enabled?
.PARAMETER Test
Switch parameter to validate the install. Performs the following:
- Displays the RSAT update file that was downloaded.
- Confirms the hotfix is installed.
- Displays help for Get-ADDomain.
- Run the cmdlets Get-ADDomain.
.EXAMPLE
Install-ADModule -Verbose
.EXAMPLE
Install-ADModule -Test -Verbose
#>
Function Install-ADModule {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [switch]$Test = $false
    )

    If ((Get-CimInstance Win32_OperatingSystem).Caption -like "*Windows 10*") {
        Write-Verbose '---This system is running Windows 10'
    } Else {
        Write-Warning '---This system is not running Windows 10'
        break
    }

    If (Get-HotFix -Id KB2693643 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {

        Write-Verbose '---RSAT for Windows 10 is already installed'

    } Else {

        Write-Verbose '---Downloading RSAT for Windows 10'

        If ((Get-CimInstance Win32_ComputerSystem).SystemType -like "x64*") {
            $dl = 'WindowsTH-KB2693643-x64.msu'
        } Else {
            $dl = 'WindowsTH-KB2693643-x86.msu'
        }
        Write-Verbose "---Hotfix file is $dl"

        Write-Verbose "---$(Get-Date)"
        #Download file sample
        #https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/files-from-websites-4a181ff3
        $BaseURL = 'https://download.microsoft.com/download/1/D/8/1D8B5022-5477-4B9A-8104-6A71FF9D98AB/'
        $URL = $BaseURL + $dl
        $Destination = Join-Path -Path $HOME -ChildPath "Downloads\$dl"
        $WebClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
        $WebClient.DownloadFile($URL,$Destination)
        $WebClient.Dispose()

        Write-Verbose '---Installing RSAT for Windows 10'
        Write-Verbose "---$(Get-Date)"
        # http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21112244/apply-service-packs-msu-file-update-using-powershell-scripts-on-local-server
        wusa.exe $Destination /quiet /norestart /log:$home\Documents\RSAT.log

        # wusa.exe returns immediately. Loop until install complete.
        do {
            Write-Host "." -NoNewline
            Start-Sleep -Seconds 3
        } until (Get-HotFix -Id KB2693643 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
        Write-Host "."
        Write-Verbose "---$(Get-Date)"
    }

    # The latest versions of the RSAT automatically enable all RSAT features
    If ((Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName `
        RSATClient-Roles-AD-Powershell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).State `
        -eq 'Enabled') {

        Write-Verbose '---RSAT AD PowerShell already enabled'

    } Else {

        Write-Verbose '---Enabling RSAT AD PowerShell'
        Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName RSATClient-Roles-AD-Powershell

    }

    Write-Verbose '---Downloading help for AD PowerShell'
    Update-Help -Module ActiveDirectory -Verbose -Force

    Write-Verbose '---ActiveDirectory PowerShell module install complete.'

    # Verify
    If ($Test) {
        Write-Verbose '---Validating AD PowerShell install'
        dir (Join-Path -Path $HOME -ChildPath Downloads\*msu)
        Get-HotFix -Id KB2693643
        Get-Help Get-ADDomain
        Get-ADDomain
    }
}


Get-Help Install-ADModule -Full

Install-ADModule -Verbose

#Install-ADModule -Test -Verbose

break

<#
# Remove
wusa.exe /uninstall /kb:2693643 /quiet /norestart /log:$home\RSAT.log
#>
```

***Result after executing the function created:***

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Install-ADModule -Verbose
VERBOSE: Perform operation 'Enumerate CimInstances' with following parameters, ''className' = Win32_OperatingSystem,'namespaceName' = root\cimv2'.
VERBOSE: Operation 'Enumerate CimInstances' complete.
VERBOSE: ---This system is running Windows 10
VERBOSE: ---Downloading RSAT for Windows 10
VERBOSE: Perform operation 'Enumerate CimInstances' with following parameters, ''className' = Win32_ComputerSystem,'namespaceName' = root\cimv2'.
VERBOSE: Operation 'Enumerate CimInstances' complete.
VERBOSE: ---Hotfix file is WindowsTH-KB2693643-x64.msu
VERBOSE: ---07/02/2018 14:51:35
VERBOSE: ---Installing RSAT for Windows 10
VERBOSE: ---07/02/2018 14:51:57
......................... (Here is where it keeps printing dots)
```

Screenshot:

[image]

**Note:** 
The version of windows I have is: Windows 10 Home 64-bit (10.0, Build 17134)

I hope you guys could help me with this.
Greetings!

Comment: It looks like installing RSAT is just taking a while, which it not unheard of. How long are you waiting? This is the command that's running:
wusa.exe $Destination /quiet /norestart /log:$home\Documents\RSAT.log
Take a look at the RSAT.log file and see if anything there jumps out at you as a problem. But it may just be a slow installation.

Comment: @jbsmith hmm for example in the morning i stopped it because it took me like 1 hour and the loop was still running, is it ok to take it more than 1 hour?, oh ok thanks!!! hmm, how do i check that .log file ?

Comment: It might be possible that Windows 10 Home does not support the RSAT windows feature. I ran into that issue a couple years ago with trying to use Hyper-V manager on windows 10 home, came to find out that you couldn't use it with the 'home' version of windows. I could definitely be wrong, but just a thought

Comment: cet51 is correct, rsat cannot be installed on win 10 home.

Comment: @cet51 thank you so much!, i just tried it in another computer with windows 10 pro and it worked out!

Comment: Glad to be of some help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

RSAT is not available on the ‘home’ versions of windows.  I ran into a similar issue with hyper-v on windows 10 home, but it worked just fine after upgrading to windows 10 pro for a fee.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to install Active Directory Module for Powershell on Windows 10 Pro

```
1. Settings->Apps->add a features: RSAT active directory domain services and lightweight directory services

this is the feature on demand

2. From powershell run as administrator: Import-Module -Name ActiveDirectory
```